# how to enable monitoring in google cloud for kubernetes through rest api

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes

Anyone can help me how to enable monitoring in google cloud through restapi.?
just like in gcloud sdk

```
gcloud services enable monitoring
```

while creating a dashboard, able to see some metrics through rest api but not enable monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Certain Google APIs are not publically accessible. As per the docs, [Enabling the Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/enable-api) can be done only via **Cloud Console** or **Cloud SDK**. Only after enabling it, you can interact with it either directly or using [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries). But it's not possible to enable this API via direct call to Google API.

Comment: Hello @sumitmadan and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!